# Establishing password less connection SunOS using expect

Tags: shell, unix, expect, sunos, password-less

The host system from where I am trying to establish remote connection is running on SunOS. There isn't ssh-copy-id available on the system. 
After searching, I found that the following command, when executed will mimic the ssh-copy-id function.

```
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh remotehost 'cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo "Host Key Copied"'
```

I am trying to write a script using expect for doing this operation but it is failing with the following error.
**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/bin/bash

set username  [lindex $argv 0]
set password  [lindex $argv 1]
set host      [lindex $argv 2]

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh remotehost 'cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo \"Host Key Copied\"'
expect "Password:"
send "$password\n"
expect eof
```

**Error:**

```
invalid command name "cat"
    while executing
"cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh remotehost 'cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys && echo \"Host Key Copied\"'"
    (file "./remote.sh" line 8)
```

From search, I understood that expect won't entertain shell commands by default. Could someone help in resolving my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: bash and expect are two different languages.

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with shell code only.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I understand that both of them are different & I am seeking help here in finding any other way possible to achieve it. I cannot install/use external modules on this server.

Comment: *"I understand that both of them are different"* -- Then you still mix them up in one script? You need to learn the basics about a language before you can really use it. At least you should find some examples and start from there.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. I don't mean to use the same script mentioned in the question. I was just trying to show what I did initially and what the error was. That is the reason I wrote, "From search, I understood that expect won't entertain shell commands by default." I am trying to find what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `spawn` command: `spawn` launches the process that you're interacting with. You're also missing the `ssh-copy-id` command:

```
spawn ssh-copy-id $username@$host
expect ...
```

However, what you're doing is *greatly* reducing security. Passing the password in clear text on the command line, where it will likely be stored in your shell's history file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. As mentioned in description, the host is running on SunOS, which lacks ssh-copy-id, which blocks me from using it.
As for the security, I understand your concern and will look for alternatives. This is for internal checks automation and as per my script, this ssh-copy-id command will be used only once for establishing the password-less connection. From next run, the script will check for password-less connection and go ahead without triggering ssh-copy-id.